# Throwing Uninitialized Planning Variable - previousStandstill (Interface) in Planning Entity for TSP with Time Window Problem

Tags: java, quarkus, optaplanner

I am working on implementing Optaplanner for Travelling Salesman Problem with Time Windows with Quarkus Rest API. I am new to the Chained Through Time Pattern. So I tried with Sample example of VRP with Time Window example. But when I triggered Rest API, I am getting unitialized "previousStandstill" while solving. I have created proper Getter and Setter for this as well.

The exception I got,

```
2021-09-06 09:48:31,390 INFO  [org.opt.cor.imp.sol.DefaultSolver] (pool-11-thread-1) Solving started: time spent (1423), best score (-6init/0hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0).
2021-09-06 09:48:31,399 DEBUG [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-11-thread-1)     CH step (0), time spent (1433), score (-5init/0hard/0soft), selected move count (16), picked move (com.vuram.optaplanner.tspwtw.domain.Job@3ed302bf {null -> com.vuram.optaplanner.tspwtw.domain.LocationPlanData@4959d41c}).
2021-09-06 09:48:31,402 DEBUG [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-11-thread-1)     CH step (1), time spent (1436), score (-4init/0hard/0soft), selected move count (16), picked move (com.vuram.optaplanner.tspwtw.domain.Job@27f20364 {null -> com.vuram.optaplanner.tspwtw.domain.LocationPlanData@4959d41c}).
2021-09-06 09:48:31,404 DEBUG [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-11-thread-1)     CH step (2), time spent (1438), score (-3init/0hard/0soft), selected move count (16), picked move (com.vuram.optaplanner.tspwtw.domain.Job@76695818 {null -> com.vuram.optaplanner.tspwtw.domain.LocationPlanData@4959d41c}).
2021-09-06 09:48:31,405 INFO  [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-11-thread-1) Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (1439), best score (-3init/0hard/0soft), score calculation speed (4083/sec), step total (3).
2021-09-06 09:48:31,420 ERROR [org.opt.cor.imp.sol.DefaultSolverManager] (pool-11-thread-1) Solving failed for problemId (b7ef1203-98dd-4b5c-8c0d-a2c1d71e4516).: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local Search phase (1) needs to start from an initialized solution, but the planning variable (Job.previousStandstill) is uninitialized for the entity (com.vuram.optaplanner.tspwtw.domain.Job@1ad10889).
Maybe there is no Construction Heuristic configured before this phase to initialize the solution.
Or maybe the getter/setters of your planning variables in your domain classes aren't implemented correctly.
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.AbstractPhase.assertWorkingSolutionInitialized(AbstractPhase.java:223)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.phaseStarted(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:119)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:65)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:99)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:175)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverJob.call(DefaultSolverJob.java:101)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Here Job (Visit in Locations) is the PlanningEntity. Here the Job Code

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Job implements Standstill {

    @PlanningId
    private Long jobId;
    private Location jobLocation;
    private Date startDateTime;
    private Date endDateTime;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "locationPlanDataList")
    private LocationPlanData locationPlanData;
    
//  @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "personList")
    protected Person person;
    
    protected Standstill previousStandstill;
    
    /* Shadow Variable */
    protected Job nextJob;
    private Date arrivalTime;

    public Job() {

    }

    public Job(Long jobId, Location jobLocation, Date startDateTime, Date endDateTime) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
        this.jobLocation = jobLocation;
        this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
        this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
    }

    /**
     * @return the jobId
     */
    public Long getJobId() {
        return jobId;
    }

    /**
     * @param jobId the jobId to set
     */
    public void setJobId(Long jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the jobLocation
     */
    @Override
    public Location getLocation() {
        return jobLocation;
    }

    /**
     * @param jobLocation the jobLocation to set
     */
    public void setJobLocation(Location jobLocation) {
        this.jobLocation = jobLocation;
    }

    /**
     * @return the startDateTime
     */
    public Date getStartDateTime() {
        return startDateTime;
    }

    /**
     * @param startDateTime the startDateTime to set
     */
    public void setStartDateTime(Date startDateTime) {
        this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
    }

    /**
     * @return the endDateTime
     */
    public Date getEndDateTime() {
        return endDateTime;
    }

    /**
     * @param endDateTime the endDateTime to set
     */
    public void setEndDateTime(Date endDateTime) {
        this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
    }

    /**
     * @return the locationPlanData
     */
    public LocationPlanData getLocationPlanData() {
        return locationPlanData;
    }

    /**
     * @param locationPlanData the locationPlanData to set
     */
    public void setLocationPlanData(LocationPlanData locationPlanData) {
        this.locationPlanData = locationPlanData;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return the previousStandstill
     */
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "jobList" }, graphType = PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED)
    public Standstill getPreviousStandstill() {
        return previousStandstill;
    }

    /**
     * @param previousStandstill the previousStandstill to set
     */
    public void setPreviousStandstill(Standstill previousStandstill) {
        this.previousStandstill = previousStandstill;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nextJob
     */
    @Override
    public Job getNextJob() {
        return nextJob;
    }

    /**
     * @param nextJob the nextJob to set
     */
    @Override
    public void setNextJob(Job nextJob) {
        this.nextJob = nextJob;
    }
    
    /**
     * Return the Departure Time
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Date getDepartureTime() {
        if (arrivalTime == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (arrivalTime.after(startDateTime)) {
            return arrivalTime;
        }
        return startDateTime;
    }

    /**
     * @return the person
     */
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param person the person to set
     */
    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return the arrivalTime
     */
    @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener.class, sources = {
            @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "previousStandstill") })
    public Date getArrivalTime() {
        return arrivalTime;
    }

    /**
     * @param arrivalTime the arrivalTime to set
     */
    public void setArrivalTime(Date arrivalTime) {
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    }
}
```

Standstill Interface Code

```
@PlanningEntity
public interface Standstill {

    /**
     * @return never null
     */
    Location getLocation();
    
    /**
     * @return sometimes null
     */
    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "previousStandstill")
    Job getNextJob();

    void setNextJob(Job nextJob);
    
}
```

I need help on resolving this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you configured any termination? The debug log suggests the Construction Heuristics (CH) did 3 steps, initializing 3 entities out of 6. Then it finished, leaving the remaining 3 entities uninitialized.
The Local Search phase requires all entities to be already initialized.

Comment: Hi @Radovan, I have configured **quarkus.optaplanner.solver.termination.spent-limit=60s** in the application.properties file. But it is terminating before (around 4s) due to this exception. Is there something, I need to change?

Comment: Your previousStandstill is a chained variable. That means you want to build a chain of Job planning entities. But every valid chain needs an anchor -- a different type that extends Standstill but is not a Job, for example a Vehicle. Don't forget to add vehicleList to previousStandstill's valueRangeProviderRefs. Please read carefully: https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#chainedPlanningVariable and see https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/main/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this smells like data corruption in the input problem (see yurloc's comment).

Temporary turn on a full assertion in your **application.properties**, and give it 10 times more termination time (to compensate for the perf loss), to flush out that corruption.

```
quarkus.optaplanner.solver.environment-mode=FULL_ASSERT
```